Conjecture about semigroups
Let $G$ be a finite semigroup with order $n$ odd. Let $S_i \in G, i=1,\ldots,\binom{n}{(n+1)/2}$ be all the subsets of $G$ of size $(n+1)/2$.
Let $E(S_i)$ be the set obtained "expanding" $S_i$ with the following rules:

if $x \in S_i$ then $x \in E(S_i)$
if $x,y \in E(S_i)$ then $xy \in E(S_i)$
if $xy \in E(S_i)$ then $x \in E(S_i)$ and $y \in E(S_i)$

I conjecture that there always exists an element $a$ contained in at least $\binom{n}{(n+1)/2}-1$ of the "expanded" sets $E(S_i), i=1,\ldots,\binom{n}{(n+1)/2}$.
Can we give a counterexample or say something about this conjecture?

Presumably your $E(S)$ is meant to be the smallest set satisfying those conditions, i.e., the closure of $S$ under iterated applications of (2) and (3)?  (Otherwise, $E(S) = G$ satisfies the stated conditions.)

@LSpice yes, you are right, I missed that condition.

I conjecture that there always exists an element $a$ contained in at least $\binom{n}{(n+1)/2}-1$ of the "expanded" sets $E(S_i), i=1,\ldots,\binom{n}{(n+1)/2}$.
(Rephrasing to better match what is below:
I conjecture that there always exists an element $a$ contained in all, except possibly $1$,
of the "expanded" sets $E(S_i), i=1,\ldots,\binom{n}{(n+1)/2}$.)
This conjecture is false. I will give a counterexample
that is a strong semilattice of groups.
Background .
(Strong semilattice of groups) 
Let $(S,\wedge)$ be a meet semilattice,
let $(G_s,\ast_s)$, $s\in S$, be an $S$-indexed family of groups, and
for $s <t$ in $S$ let $\varphi_{t,s}\colon G_t\to G_s$
be a group homomorphism. Assume that (i) when $r\leq s\leq t$
we have $\varphi_{s,r}\circ \varphi_{t,s}=\varphi_{t,r}$
and (ii)
when $s=t$ the homomorphism
$\varphi_{t,s}=\varphi_{s,s}$ is the identity
endomorphism of $G_s$. The associated strong
semilattice of groups, $\mathcal S$,
has universe equal to the disjoint
union $\sqcup_{s\in S} G_s$ and has multiplication
defined by the rule: $x\in G_s$, $y\in G_t$ implies
$xy = \varphi_{s,s\wedge t}(x)\ast_{s\wedge t} \varphi_{t,s\wedge t}(y)$.
This is a semigroup multiplication.
(Character supports) 
Let $\mathbf{2}$ be the subsemigroup of
the multiplicative semigroup $(\mathbb R,\cdot)$
with universe $\{0,1\}$. This is a $2$-element (meet) semilattice.
If $S$ is any semigroup, call a homomorphism $\chi\colon S\to \mathbf{2}$
a character and call $\chi^{-1}(1)$ the support of $\chi$.
A subset $U\subseteq S$ of a semigroup $S$ is a character support
if and only if $xy\in U \Leftrightarrow (x\in U)\& (y\in U)$.
Character supports are closed under intersection, since if
$\chi, \chi'\colon S\to \mathbf{2}$ have supports $U, U'$,
then the product character $(\chi\cdot \chi')(x):=\chi(x)\cdot \chi'(x)$
has support $U\cap U'$. Therefore, if $S$ is a finite semigroup,
each subset $U\subseteq S$ is contained in (or 'generates')
a smallest character support. In the problem statement,
this smallest character support containing $U$
is denoted $E(U)$ and is called the set obtained
by 'expanding' $U$.
Foreground.
(The example.) 
Let $R=\{1,2,\ldots,r\}$, $r>0$, and let $S$ be the meet
semilattice whose elements are the proper subsets of $R$
and whose operation is intersection.
This semilattice is the power set $\mathcal{P}(R)$ without the top
element under the operation of intersection.
Choose a finite group $H$.
For each $s\in S$ define $G_s$ to be $H$
if $s$ is a maximal proper subset of $R$.
Define $G_s$ to be the $1$-element group, $\mathbf{1}$, otherwise.
The maps $\varphi_{t,s}$ are completely determined
by this information: when $s=t$ we must have
$\varphi_{s,s}=\textrm{id}_{G_s}$ and when $s<t$
we must have $\varphi_{t,s}\colon H\to \mathbf{1}$
the constant homomorphism.
The associated strong semilattice
of groups has a copy of $H$ living at each
maximal element of ${\mathcal P}(R)-\{R\}$
and a copy of $\mathbf{1}$
living at each `submaximal' element of
${\mathcal P}(R)-\{R\}$. ('Submaximal'
means: strictly below some maximal element.)
If $h:=|H|$, then the
size of our semigroup
$\mathcal S$ is $rh+ (2^r - r - 1)\;(=r(h-1)+(2^r-1))$.
This counts the $r$ copies of $H$ living at the
maximal elements of ${\mathcal P}(R)-\{R\}$
together with one copy of $\mathbf{1}$ living at
each submaximal element of ${\mathcal P}(R)-\{R\}$.
The size of this semigroup can be odd,
e.g. $|\mathcal S|$ is odd
whenever $r$ is even or whenever $r$ and $h$ are both odd.
(I am mentioning that $|\mathcal S|$ can be odd, since
that is one of the restrictions in the problem.)
Claim.
For each $a\in \mathcal S$ there are at least
$$
\binom{(r-1)(h-1)+(2^{r-1}-1)}{\frac{r(h-1)}{2}+2^{r-1}}
$$
sets of the form $E(S_i)$ that fail to contain $a$.
(For example, if $r=4$, this says that there are at least
$\binom{3h+4}{2h+6}$ sets of the form $E(S_i)$ that fail to contain $a$.
This number is greater than $1$ whenever
$h=|H|>2$, hence the conjecture in the problem statement
is false.)

Reasoning for Claim.
Choose any $a\in \mathcal S$. Then $a\in G_U$ for some
$U\in {\mathcal P}(R)-\{R\}$.
$U$ is a proper subset of $R$, so there is some $k\in R-U$.
The set $Y$ of all $y\in \mathcal S$ such that $y\in G_V$
for some $V$ containing $k$ is a character support that does not contain $a$.
[Showing that $Y$ is a character support of $\mathcal S$
reduces to showing that an intersection of sets
$V, V'\in {\mathcal P}(R)-\{R\}$ will contain $k$ iff
both $V$ and $V'$ contain $k$.]
The size of $Y$ can be computed to be
$(r-1)(h-1)+(2^{r-1}-1)$.
The main takeaway from this paragraph is that for
any $a\in \mathcal S$ there is a relatively
large character support $Y$ such that $a\notin Y$.
Now, following the notation of the problem statement, use $S_i$
to represent some subset of $\mathcal S$
that has size $(|\mathcal S|+1)/2$.
Since $Y$ is a character support and $E(S_i)$ is the least
character support containing $S_i$, we derive that
$S_i\subseteq Y$ implies $E(S_i)\subseteq Y$,
which further implies that $a\notin E(S_i)$.
Thus, $a$ does not belong to any $E(S_i)$ where
$S_i$ is a subset of $Y$ of size
$(|\mathcal S|+1)/2$. The number of subsets of
$Y$ of size $(|\mathcal S|+1)/2$ can be computed
in terms of $r$ and $h$ to be
$$
\binom{(r-1)(h-1)+(2^{r-1}-1)}{\frac{r(h-1)}{2}+2^{r-1}}. \Box
$$

(One sentence summary: There is a semigroup $\mathcal S$ such that for every $a\in \mathcal S$ there is a large character support $Y$ that does not contain $a$, therefore $a$ does not belong to the many character supports of the form $E(S_i)$ that are subsets of $Y$.)
